# Why does England have 8 places in Europe while Spain and Germany only have 7?

Tags: football, uefa, champions-league

You can see the [coefficient rankings here](http://www.uefa.com/memberassociations/uefarankings/country/)

Spain and Germany are first and second, while England is third. However, Spain and Germany only have 7 places available, but England has eight. Why is this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every year 3 countries get 1 more berth in the uefa europa league first qualifying round based on countries fair play rankings. Based on last year ranking England got that 1 extra spot and West Ham were the highest placed team in the fair play ranking that have not qualified to the champions league or europa league they qualified for the first qualifying round of the europa league